# request.getParameter returning null in a Post Servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, parameter-passing

I have an index.jsp that has the following code

**index.xml**

```
<form method="post" action ="LoginServlet" >

    <p> USER ID: </p> <input type='text' name='user' />
    <br>
    <p> PASSWORD: </p> <input type='password' name='pass'/>
    <br> 
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

And I have a loginServlet that has the code

**LoginServlet**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {

        String user = request.getParameter("user");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
```

Somehow, the parameter is not being passed into the variables that I set in my servlet. From what i've researched, most answers would direct me to correct my "post" method in my jsp. I've done it so, but still have no luck with my code.

I could provide more info on my entire project if needed.
Sorry if this may seem repetitive, but most answers i've seen, i've already done. Sorry in advance.

Comment: You need to make sure first that your servlet is indeed called when the form is submitted.

Comment: How do i make sure it does?

Comment: make sure to set correctly url-pattern and servlet-mapping in your web.xml

Comment: Ohh. wait. I think it already does. I have a condition inside my servlet that would redirect my jsp to another jsp if the password and user is incorrect. The problem is that every time that submit a username and password, it always return null values for both, so the condition would always comeback false because there is nothing to compare it to.